# Running two REST APIs sequentially in SPFX webpart (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, typescript

I'm new to typescript and spfx SharePoint online webpart development. I've got a requirement where I need to run a REST api and wait for its result before I run the next one. I am kind of lost. I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction to do this right. I basically want to run getLibraryIcons first and get all results before I run the other getLibraries. I want to use the results from library icons with the results I get from getLibraries. Thank you!

some of the related code I have in my webpart

```
export interface SPLibraryList
{
  value: SPLibraryItem[];
}

export interface SPLibraryItem {
  Title: string;  
  Description: string;
  DocumentTemplateUrl:string;
}

export interface SPIconList
{
  value: SPIconItem[];
}

export interface SPIconItem {
  Title: string;  
  Url: string;  
}
```

and then

```
public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="${ styles.siteLibraries }">
        <div id="spLibrariesList"></div>
        
      </div>`;
      this.renderLibraries();
    /*let tileInfo = this.getIcons();*/

    
    
  }

 protected renderLibraries(): void {
    let listItemInfo: string = "";  
    const libraryImage: any = require('./assets/DocLibIcon.png');

    let icons = this.getLibraryIcons()
    let libraries = this.getLibraries();
   /* this is where I want to go through each array of objects and do some logic*/
 }

protected getLibraries(): Promise<SPLibraryList> {
    let currentWebUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
    let requestUrl = currentWebUrl.concat("/_api/web/lists?$filter=(BaseTemplate eq 101) and (Title ne 'Site Assets') and (Hidden eq false)&orderby=Title");   
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
    .then((responseLibraries: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
      if (responseLibraries.ok) { 
         return responseLibraries.json();
      }
        
    });  
  }

  protected getLibraryIcons(): Promise<SPIconList> {
    let currentWebUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
    let requestUrl = currentWebUrl.concat("/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Document%20Library%20Icons')/items?$select=Title,URL");   
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
    .then((responseIcons: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
         
         if (responseIcons.ok) {  
          return responseIcons.json();
         }
        
    });  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute this 2 request in order, you can put the second one in the callback of the first one.

```
getLibraryIcons().then(res=>{
  console.log(res);
  getLibraries().then(v=>{    
    console.log(res);  
    console.log(v);  
  });  
});
```

BR

Comment: Thanks! This worked!

Answer (score 0):

Its time that you learn implementing async/await calls instead of using callbacks when in SPFx.
You need to make you renderlibrary() as a async function and use await call for the  getLibraryIcons and getLibraries function.

your functions will look like

```
const renderLibraries = async() =>{

const response1 = await getLibraryIcons();
const response2 = await getLibraries(response1)

}

const getLibraryIcons = async() =>{
 const output =  await this.context.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
//..... your code here
return response.json()
}
const getLibraries = async() =>{

 const output =  await this.context.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
//..... your code here
return response.json()

}
```